# Why would keytool report 'NoSuchAlgorithmException; cannot support algorithm "RSA"'?

Tags: java, keytool

I thought I would share the workaround I discovered today.  It is not possible to create an RSA key in the manner I'm used to anymore....

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Install Java Development Kit jdk-6u30-windows-x64.exe on a Windows Server 2008 R2. Include the Public JRE.
2. Run the JRE's bin\keytool utility with the following parameters:

   `keytool -genseckey -alias FOO -keystore FOO.jks -keyalg RSA -validity 1825`

**Expected results**:

Self signed certificate creation wizard

**Actual results**:

NoSuchAlgorithmException; cannot support algorithm "RSA"

**Workaround**:

Of course I tried using lowercase "rsa" but this did not work.
What worked was to use the undocumented former method "-genkey" instead of "-genseckey"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`-genkey` is obsolete parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#genkeypairCmd), in jdk6 is was replaced by -genkeypair. Use `-genkeypair` instead of `-genseckey` if you want to generate RSA keypair.